# What's the safest way to electronically brake a PMA wind generator to prevent overspeed damage to stator?

Tags: stator

I have a couple 24 volt 400W wind turbines on order for my 24 volt off-grid system I already have set up with 2000 watts of solar, inverter and generator.

The included charge controller schematic indicates the ability to short the three-phase AC as an electronic braking mechanism.

I see on YouTube some people are running custom setups with load resistors switched in series to provide a slight constant braking, and applying a heavy short-term load in order to brake speed down, then shorting across the rectified output to park the turbine in a windstorm.

My question is which method is safer for the windings on the stator of the PMA generator: shorting the three AC phases or the DC output of a rectifier from those same three phases?

I've seen burnt stators from 3 phase shorted braking, maybe if the turbine is still turning with brakes on is causing this?

Comment: a shorted output will not completely stop the turbine ... applying a short circuit before or after the rectifier will make no difference to the generator

Comment: have you considered mechanical braking?

Comment: If you short the output (small difference before or after rectification) then you are dissipating ALL the wind energy in the windings. If this is the only braking system on the generator then you can clearly damage the windings in high winds. You should have a physical brake for best safety.

Comment: Not sure why no wind generators seem to do this, but if you could rotate the attack angle of the blades *into* the wind, the speed *and* power will drop - no braking required, and less chance of mechanical damage in high-wind conditions.

Comment: what type of of a turbine are you using? ... if it is a windmill type, then you could orient the turbine sideways to the wind

Comment: So, rotate the rotor out of the wind to avoid overspeed…

Comment: they're less than a KW units, I was debating on splurging for a 2KW "windsafe" mount that just tilts back when the wind it too strong, or one of the ones that hinge at the tailfin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your analysis is pretty straightforward.  When your generator is in its operational range, the torque of your generator is directly proportional to the current, and the speed is directly proportional to the voltage.  When the turbine is spinning and is shorted, you are instantly bringing the voltage to zero, so the generator will stop quickly.  The torque required to stop the generator is not only the torque from the wind on the blades, but also the torque necessary to decelerate the spinning mass of the turbine.  The generator coils will see a large peak current.  A rough estimate of this peak current is the voltage present when the phases are shorted divided by the phase resistance of the coil.  This will be many times the rated current of the turbine, and if it is allowed to persist it will result in the heating of the coil.

Depending on the turbine's rotational inertia, the torque from the wind, and the coil resistance, the shorted turbine decelerates and dissipates much of the energy in the windings, which can cause the overheating you have seen.  The "safe" approach is to monitor and limit the applied load to keep the current in a safe range while the turbine decelerates. For turbines with low inertia and those producing limited torque, simply shorting the phases may suffice because the turbine will stop quickly before excessive heating occurs.  Using an external resistance has the advantage that most of the energy is absorbed externally rather than in the coils.  You might experiment with shorting the coils into a load until the turbine slows before shorting them completely.  Shorting through the rectifier simplifies the circuitry as long as your approach doesn't exceed the rectifier's current specs.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! So I guess the best compromise saving a mechanical solution would be to use a large external resistive load to slow it down before shorting the windings to park. As long as it stays motionless in the strong winds then it should be ok.

Maybe the ones that burnt up had winds so high that the blades would start turning again after being slowed and parked shorted, or during overspeed the controller or operator just shorted the windings and left it spinning rather than apply a large load to slow/stop the blades first before parking. 

Thanks again.

Comment: I agree - I would think it's the best approach.  If your windings get hot enough so that the insulation fails, you can have a short with only a few turns or even a single turn.